# Fork instruction

Tags: c, operating-system

My question is about the fork() instruction in C. I have the following program:

```
void main(){
   int result, status;
   result = fork();
   if(result==0){
      printf("Son:%d\n", getpid());
   }else{
      printf("Pai..:%d\n", getpid());
      wait(&status);
   }
}
```

Why do I receive the two `printf`, instead of only one? Is it because of the return of the `fork`?
My another question is about the & before status. Why do I need it there?

Comment: What is your understanding of what `fork()` does?

Comment: Sometimes actually reading the manual is neccessary: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

Comment: Also, `main` should return `int`, though you can leave the return-statement out since C99.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth my understanding of fork() is that it creates another process, the son. When it creates it copies all the variables, arguments and the code itself to the son. Creates a new PID and if the father wasn't killed it has the PPID of him

Comment: @Deduplicator Ohhh I'm sorry if I bother you. But normally when people post questions is because they don't understand what was explained

Comment: That may be, but quite often it is because they didn't bother to do any research, like reading the reference-page. Your question did not and still does not show any sign that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fork systemcall returns the processid of the childprocess to the parentprocess and 0 to the childprocess. One Time the code in your if clause will be executed(by son) and one time the else clause(by parent).

This means that printf is invoked two times.

Wait is another systemcall, which blocks execution until one of the childprocesses returns.
Instead of giving answer by returning some value, wait gives you the information by writing it to a address.

You pass wait the variable status. If you pass it without & wait would get the current value of status. By adding a &, you pass the address of status to wait. Once a childprocess terminated, wait will stop and the information will be stored in status. The process which just terminated is returned

Here the Linux Man Page for wait:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html

Answer (score 2):

fork is an operation whereby a process creates a copy of itself. It is usually a system call, implemented in the kernel. Fork is the primary method of process creation on Unix-like operating systems.n multitasking operating systems, processes (running programs) need a way to create new processes

When a process calls fork, it is deemed the parent process, and the newly created process, its child. After the fork, both processes not only run the same program, but they resume execution as though both had called the system call. They can then inspect the call's return value to determine their status, child or parent, and act accordingly.

```
    /* Includes */
#include <unistd.h>     /* Symbolic Constants */
#include <sys/types.h>  /* Primitive System Data Types */ 
#include <errno.h>      /* Errors */
#include <stdio.h>      /* Input/Output */
#include <sys/wait.h>   /* Wait for Process Termination */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* General Utilities */

int main()
{
    pid_t childpid; /* variable to store the child's pid */
    int retval;     /* child process: user-provided return code */
    int status;     /* parent process: child's exit status */

    /* only 1 int variable is needed because each process would have its
       own instance of the variable
       here, 2 int variables are used for clarity */

    /* now create new process */
    childpid = fork();

    if (childpid >= 0) /* fork succeeded */
    {
        if (childpid == 0) /* fork() returns 0 to the child process */
        {
            printf("CHILD: I am the child process!\n");
            printf("CHILD: Here's my PID: %d\n", getpid());
            printf("CHILD: My parent's PID is: %d\n", getppid());
            printf("CHILD: The value of my copy of childpid is: %d\n", childpid);
            printf("CHILD: Sleeping for 1 second...\n");
            sleep(1); /* sleep for 1 second */
            printf("CHILD: Enter an exit value (0 to 255): ");
            scanf(" %d", &retval);
            printf("CHILD: Goodbye!\n");    
            exit(retval); /* child exits with user-provided return code */
        }
        else /* fork() returns new pid to the parent process */
        {
            printf("PARENT: I am the parent process!\n");
            printf("PARENT: Here's my PID: %d\n", getpid());
            printf("PARENT: The value of my copy of childpid is %d\n", childpid);
            printf("PARENT: I will now wait for my child to exit.\n");
            wait(&status); /* wait for child to exit, and store its status */
            printf("PARENT: Child's exit code is: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            printf("PARENT: Goodbye!\n");             
            exit(0);  /* parent exits */       
        }
    }
    else /* fork returns -1 on failure */
    {
        perror("fork"); /* display error message */
        exit(0); 
    }
}
```